# Sort posts by Date (DESC) and by Title (ASC)

Tags: functions, query, order

Currently, the posts of my website are ordered alphabetically by title:

```
/* Order Posts Alphabetically */
function prefix_modify_query_order( $query ) {
  if ( is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'prefix_modify_query_order' );
```

Now, I want to sort the posts alphabetically by title (ascending), but also by date (descending).

Like this example:

- AUDI A1 Ambition 1.4 (posted in 01/01/17)
- AUDI A1 Ambition 1.4 (posted in 01/01/16)
- AUDI A1 Ambition 1.4 (posted in 01/01/15)
- BMW 120i Active Flex 2.0 (posted in 01/01/17)
- BMW 120i Active Flex 2.0 (posted in 01/01/16)
- BMW 120i Active Flex 2.0 (posted in 01/01/15)
- Citroen...

Changing the `orderby` parameter to `$query->set( 'orderby', 'date title' );` does not resolve my problem because I need to show the most recent posts first.

I would appreciate any other ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass an array to the `query` as the following example described in the  [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) shows:

```
$args = array(
'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'DESC', 'menu_order' => 'ASC' )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In your case will be something like this:

```
/* Order Posts Alphabetically */
function prefix_modify_query_order( $query ) {
  if ( is_main_query() ) {

    $args =  array( 'post_date' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' );

    $query->set( 'orderby', $args );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'prefix_modify_query_order' );
```

If you want the `post_date` as the primary filter, you have to change his position in the array, now the code will query all the posts alphabetically starting by the newest post_date.

Comment: I improved the code, see now if works for you

Comment: Yes mate, I was about to wright an answer saying that I've put the post_date first in your code and it worked, but you changed your answer first. Yes, it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :D, if you can please mark as the correct answer or post your answer please, it will help other people with the same question, thanks!