# how to develop a filter in wordpress to let the user filter the page content depends on the date (newest to oldest etc...)?

Tags: filters, sort

how to develop a filter in WordPress to let the user sort the page content depends on (alphabetically, newest to oldest and oldest to newest etc...)?

I’d like another drop down tab on the left side of the page that users can select videos by genre, is there a plugin doing this functions or is there a source I can learn doing this functions from?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at FacetWP plugin, which is a paid plugin, but it does all of this and more:

https://facetwp.com/

If you want to manually do this, there's numerous ways based on what specifically you're referring to (blog posts?  custom post types?):
[Sort posts by Date (DESC) and by Title (ASC)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272072/sort-posts-by-date-desc-and-by-title-asc)

WordPress also has native widgets like categories and others that will do most of this for you.